# Base64 svg support in outlook desktop client and conversion of base64 svg to base64 png with custom bgcolor

Tags: c#, svg, outlook, base64, email-templates

I am using base64 encoded svg images in the email template `<img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,XXXXXXX<base64 encoded image>">`.
[image]

This image works fine in web  browser but fails to render in Outlook Desktop client.

Is there a way to make the svg+xml formal work in outlook client? may be using `<!--[if mso]>`

Or can someone sugeest me a way to convert a base64 svg to base64 png with **custom background color** in c#? I don't want to create an intermeditate image as png and want to directly convert base64 image to png base64.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Base64 support in HTML emails is very limited (see https://www.caniemail.com/features/image-base64/) and I wouldn't recommend to use it.

Comment: my client is ok with Base64 as they are planning to use it on latest outlook version

Answer (score 0):

Word (which is used to render HTML images in Outlook) does not support base64 embedded HTML images.